# What kind of map is the inversion map on groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups. Suppose $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ is a map such that $\phi(g g') = \phi(g') \phi(g)$ for all $g,g' \in G$. What is the name for such a map? For example, if $H = G$, then $\phi : G \rightarrow G$ could be the map which takes $g$ to $g^{-1}$. If $G$ and $H$ are abelian, then any such map $\phi$ is just a group homomorphism. Structure-preserving maps of this type seem to pop up quite a bit, even outside of groups, but I haven't been able to find the standard name for them.

Comment: This is called an [antihomomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihomomorphism).

Comment: Category-theorists use the word "contravariant" in this context. Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821334/where-is-the-notion-of-anti-isomorphism-useful/1821393